# Count strings inside array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is my parse.com "currentUploads" class:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEv17.png)

How can I count the amount of strings inside the array? As you can see on the first row, there is 1, and on the last one, it is 3. How can I return this count in a `println`? I have tried this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"currentUploads")
            query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objID)
            query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    print("The number is \(count) in total")
                }
            }
```

I know there is missing something using the "likedBy", but I dont know where to do what. Any ideas please?

Comment: Which array? You have many instances, each with their own array...

Comment: @Wain I want to count the number of strings in "likedBy", and return as `println`.

Comment: For all objects, or a specific one ?

Comment: @Wain - For specific the column "likedBy".

Comment: But you understand that the column is really an attribute on each instance, where an instance is represented by a row in your screenshot? You can count rows, within limits, but you can't count columns in rows...

Comment: @Wain I dont want to count columns in row, i want to count a specific column.

Comment: You can't do it. At least not in this way. You would need to iterate all rows

Comment: @Wain Lets say all users is saved in a column with the name "allUsers". How can i count how many users there is in this column?

Comment: Download the item (row) and count the column contents

Comment: @Wain Could you give an code example?

Comment: why do you want to count them all?

Comment: @Wain To know the amount? Example if i save all the users that thumb up a image, so there will be multiple usernames inside the column cell, i want to count the amount and put it on a label.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to count all the entries in an array column across all instances (rows) is to iterate the instances in cloud code and count each. This is done simply using the [`each`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_each) query and summing up the `length` of each array then returning the result.

A similar thing can be done on the client, but you'll need to deal with pagination yourself as `PFQuery` doesn't offer `each`. In this case you would iterate the `objects` in each query response and sum the `count` of each array.

Comment: I get the object ID for the current row using `query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objID)`.

Comment: fine. so you can count the number of items in its array, but getting a single item at a time isn't ideal for counting all